# Add data to session in play framework filter

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm having problems with adding data to session in filter (EssentialFilter).

In scala api there is method `Result.withSession` and `Result.withNewSession` but there isn't any in java api.

How can I return a result from filter with new session data?

Tried to do it like this:

```
@Override
public EssentialAction apply(final EssentialAction next) {
    return EssentialAction.of( request -> {
        if (isAllowed(request)) {
            Accumulator<ByteString, Result> accumulator = next.apply(request);
            return accumulator.map(result -> {
                Session session = result.session();
                session.put("asdf", Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                return result;
            }, executor);
        } else {
            return Accumulator.done(Results.unauthorized());
        }
    });
}
```

From what I see in debug/sources, by the time result is back in accumulator map block, result has builded ResponseHeader, and modification of session doesn't change a thing.

I've tried to convert result to scala with `asScala()` and supply new session items (`withSession()`) but I'm having problems converting java Session to scala/play Session. Maybe somebody could point out how to do it right?

```
Session session = result.session();
session.put("asdf", Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));

play.api.mvc.Session newSession = ...?

return result.asScala().withSession(newSession).asJava();
```

**[edit]**

I got this working with:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map<String, String> immutableMap = new scala.collection.immutable.HashMap<String,String>().empty();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : session.entrySet()) {
  immutableMap = immutableMap.$plus(new Tuple2<>(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}
play.api.mvc.Session newSession = new play.api.mvc.Session(immutableMap);
```

but... as you can see it's really ugly. Isn't there any other, fancier way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you convert your filter completely to scala. Even there it is not painless, but, better than that 'ugly' code as you also agree.

An example would be:

```
  import akka.stream.Materializer
  import javax.inject._
  import play.api.Logger
  import play.api.mvc._
  import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

  @Singleton
  class ExampleFilter @Inject()(
                                   implicit override val mat: Materializer,
                                   exec: ExecutionContext) extends Filter {


    override def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])
                      (requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
      // Run the next filter in the chain. This will call other filters
      // and eventually call the action. Take the result and modify it
      // by adding a new header.

      val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
      nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
        val end = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        Logger.debug(s"Service time in milliseconds: ${end}")
        result.withSession(requestHeader.session + ("ServiceTime" -> s"${end}"))
      }
    }

  }
```

Probably you know that, but consider this as encouragement to use scala for that part only.

Unfortunately Java for play does not really fit well. You frequently get into issues about conversions. Really painful...

**edit:**

In order to include the scala filter among your java filters you should do the following in your `Filters.java`: (modified from the play-java sample) (important part : `exampleFilter.asJava()`

```
@Singleton
public class Filters implements HttpFilters {

  private final Environment env;
  private final EssentialFilter exampleFilter;

  @Inject
  public Filters(Environment env, ExampleFilter exampleFilter) {
    this.env = env;
    this.exampleFilter = exampleFilter.asJava();
  }

  @Override
  public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
    // Use the example filter if we're running development mode. If
    // we're running in production or test mode then don't use any
    // filters at all.
    if (env.mode().equals(Mode.DEV)) {
      return new EssentialFilter[]{exampleFilter};
    } else {
      return new EssentialFilter[]{};
    }
  }
}
```